# YII2: LOGIN SESSION sign on across multiple subdomains

Tags: session, authentication, subdomain, yii2

How can i configure my aplication in YII2 , for login to work in subdomain.
I'm using advanced template

Comment: You could simply use the same cookie...

Answer (score 3):

You can config same here in your main.php

```
'user' => [
     'identityClass' => 'common\models\User',
     'enableAutoLogin' => true,
     'identityCookie' => [
          'name' => '_mydomain',
          'domain' => '.mydomain.com',
          'path' => '/',
     ]
],
```